# jquerycropping,CodeIgniter,php

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I want to crop the image using jQuery, CodeIgniter

In jquery I get four coordinate  of image `x1=249 x2=326 y1=194 y2=271 w=77 h=77`

In CodeIgniter done the query

```
function do_crop()
{

    $x=249; 
    $y=194; 
    $w=77; 
    $h=77; 
    $path= 'system/application/';   
    $config = array(
        'image_library' => 'gd2',
        'source_image' => $path.'/jag1/flowers.jpg' , 
        'new_image' => $path.'/jag2/flowers.jpg',
        'maintain_ration' => false, 
        'width' => $w,
        'height' => $h,
        'x_axis' => $x,
        'y_axis' => $y
    );

    $this->load->library('image_lib');
    $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
    if ( ! $this->image_lib->crop())
    {
        echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
    }       
    $this->image_lib->clear();
}
```

I get cropped image. But problem is don't get exact cropped image x,y coordinate  problem

Please correct the coordinate

Answer (score 0):

Use `.offset()` to get the exacty x/y of your image.

The `x1` is most likely the `x1` of the mouse on the screen - so in this case 249 needs to be reduced by the `x` of the image you're selecting.

Reduce the X values by the image's `.offset().left` and the y values by `.offset().top` and then send to php.